# ElasticSearch indexing issue ,failed to parse timestamp

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, logstash, jodatime

i am new to ELK .
i have created index in Elasticsearch

```
{
  "logstash": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "log": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "message_field": {
              "path_match": "message",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "norms": false,
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "string_fields": {
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "norms": false,
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "include_in_all": false
          },
          "activity": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "beat": {
            "properties": {
              "hostname": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": false,
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": false,
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              },
              "version": {
                "type": "text",
                "norms": false,
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "filename": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "host": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "input_type": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false
          },
          "offset": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "include_in_all": false,
            "format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "user": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1488805244467",
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "5ijhh193Tr6y_hxaQrW9kg",
        "version": {
          "created": "5020199"
        },
        "provided_name": "logstash"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is my logstash configuration

```
input{
    beats{
        port=>5044
    }
}filter{
    grok{
        match=>{"message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] ALL AUDIT: User \[%{GREEDYDATA:user}\] is %{GREEDYDATA:activity} \[%{GREEDYDATA:filename}\] for transfer."}
    }
}output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts=>"localhost:9200"
        index=> "logstash"
    }
```

Sample Data

```
[2017-03-05 12:37:21.465] ALL AUDIT: User [user1] is opening file [filename1] for transfer.
```

but when i am loading file through filebeat > logstash > elasticsearch 
in elasticsearch i am getting below error

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [timestamp]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2017-03-05T12:36:33.606" is malformed at "12:36:33.606"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187) ~[joda-time-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
```

Please help , what timestamp format should i configure ?

Comment: By the way, if my answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. It helps keep the focus on unanswered questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your timestamp mapping you indicate the format as `"format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS"` Here the format you are sending through beats is not the same, check: `2017-03-05T12:36:33.606`

That's why Elastic is complaining about the format. Your format should be: `"YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"`  (notice the capital T)

See the documentation for more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: Thanks @asettouf for replying . issue resolved after changing date-time pattern to joda format - "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"